# How to extract shared components from Next.js into an npm module?

Tags: typescript, npm, sass, next.js, css-modules

I have a Next.js application, which not only has pages, but also some components. These components are written in TypeScript (so we're essentially talking `.tsx` here), and they use *CSS Modules*, using Next.js's `*.module.css` pattern – or, to be more precise, they use *CSS Modules* combined with Next.js's SASS support, so we're talking `*.module.sass` here. So far, everything works fine.

Now I would like to create a second Next.js app, and I need some of the components in both applications. Of course, I could copy / paste them, but this is a bad idea for obvious reasons. What I would like to do is to extract the shared components into an npm module of their own, and use that in both applications. Now this is the tricky part.

I don't want to precompile the shared code, to allow the respective Next.js application to do the compilation for the application code *and* the UI library code, but I don't know how to accomplish this. Of course, it's easy to setup an npm module which just contains plain `*.tsx` and `*.module.sass` files, but how do I make the final Next.js application compile them, too?

AFAICS Next.js only compiles components and styles that are contained in the application itself, not those defined in modules installed via npm. Is there any way to enable this?

PS: I'm aware of the [next-transpile-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules) module, but I'd rather prefer a somewhat more "official" approach, if there is any…

Comment: The "official" best practice is to pre-compile node modules. I'm using next-transpile-modules it does it work great!

Comment: But if you precompile, you lose Next.js's ability to code-split the precompiled things, don't you?

Comment: Nope, it depends on how you precompile it, check common libs such as react-router / i18next etc... you will see that they export several types to dist (esm, cjs) and webpack (the engine under the hood of next.js) chooses the proper module type per env (server / client).